# Trying to get post ID outside loop on blog page

Tags: php, posts, id

I have a blog index page which only lists 1 custom post at a time on the index page (it is paginated). I am trying to get the ID of that post from outside the loop (in the footer, after the loop) but am unable to do so. When I call it, i get the ID of the next post **not** the current one.

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;  // return ID of the next post, not the current one. not sure why.
```

I know that this is an unusual setup (my index page is basically a single post page). Should I change my index page design, or is there a simple way for me to just get the current post ID without throwing away all my current work?

Comment: It feels like a bit of a hack but you could store the post ID in a global variable in your loop and read that variable from the footer.

Comment: The reason it is happening: `the_post()` iterates the index in the array of posts being looped.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/

Comment: Try using `get_previous_post()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_previous_post/.  That will return the whole post object though so $var->ID to get the ID.

Comment: thanks. it's an odd solution, but i understand why (thanks for the reference link)

Comment: thanks @jdm2112 - in the end i decided to refactor the code differently so that i make the  call inside the loop instead. makes it neater.